# Customizing an IPagedCollectionView to sort on the server?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, sorting

I have a PagedCollectionView class that implements the IPagedCollectionView interface so I can use the MVVM model in Silverlight.  The problem I'm running into is that sorting of the columns happens on the client side, so only the ten items that are returned get sorted.

Is there another interface my PagedCollectionView needs to implement in order to catch the sorting events and try doing it on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IPagedCollectionView` is implemented in conjunction with implementing `ICollectionView`. It's the latter interface that exposes sorting information.

Also, `PagedCollectionView` provides a default implementation of `IPagedCollectionView` that you can likely leverage.